# AFJsonRequest and Unit-Testing needs for synchronous request,

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, afnetworking, synchronous

I'm trying to do some unit-testing on my code.
I'm facing an issue, unit-testing fonctions aren't waiting for the asynchronous request to be finished. I'd like to wait for it only if i'm testing it, and not when i run it.

I figured out how to check for this :

```
if([[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment] objectForKey:@"TARGET"] isEqualToString:@"TEST"])
```

With the respective environnement variables set in my project.
But i can't find a proper way to wait for it. I tryed with a semaphore, and that works, but i'm wandering if there's any other way which would be easier, and reader-friendly.

EDIT :

Finally, i did it like this : I guess i could have do something better, but that works and looks fair enough to me.

```
static int statusCode;

- (void)requestContent:(NSString*)urlString
{
statusCode = 0;
NSLog(@"Request Content");
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
{
    [self ParseGoogleImageSearchResponse:JSON];
    statusCode = 1;
    NSLog(@"Done");
}
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);
    statusCode = 2;
}];
[operation start];

if([[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment] objectForKey:@"TARGET"] isEqualToString:@"TEST"])
{
    while(statusCode == 0)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSLog(@"WAITING");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish async unit tests for AFNetworking calls is to use [GHUnit](http://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit).

GHUnit handles spinning the runloop and waiting for async operations to finish automatically, so your unit test code can be much more readable.

Here is a [basic tutorial](http://nscookbook.com/2013/03/recipe-18-unit-testing-with-ghunit-cocoapods/) that covers using AFNetworking, GHUnit, and [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) all together.

Here is a basic test written using AFNetworking and GHUnit.

```
- (void)test
{
    [self prepare];

    __block NSError     *responseError  = nil;
    __block id          resposeObject   = nil;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
    {
        resposeObject = JSON;       
        [self notify:kGHUnitWaitStatusSuccess forSelector:_cmd];
    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
    {
        responseError = error       
        [self notify:kGHUnitWaitStatusSuccess forSelector:_cmd];
    }];
    [operation start];

    // Wait for the async activity to complete
    [self waitForStatus:kGHUnitWaitStatusSuccess timeout:kNetworkTimeout];

    // Check Error
    GHAssertNil(responseError, @"");
    GHAssertNotNil(resposeObservation, @"Response Observation is nil");

    // Validate data...
}
```

Hope that helps!